# Tails sets are Borel

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I am trying to proof a particular case of Kolmogorov's law in the set E of infinite binary sequences. Eventually, I'm supposed to prove that a certain type of subsets of this set is in the Borel sigma algebra of a certain metric.

It's the following:
In E, we define the distance of two sequences $ x, y $ as the infinite sum of $\sum{|x_n-y_n|2^{-n}}$ which easily makes E a compact metric space.
A subset S of E is a tail if for every $y$ for which there is a $x$ in S such that $x, y$ are eventually the same, then $y$ is in S. Then we must show that every tail is borel. But it does not seem true. I can reduce tails to arbitrary unions of closed sets, but not for countable unions. What am I missing?

Comment: Anything is a union of closed sets (singletons are closed), so unfortunately your finding is not much of a "reduction".

Comment: (Anyway, you are right hat this is false without additional assumptions.)

Comment: So apparently this is false. Which assumptions are needed to make it true?

Comment: Maybe the question is the following, or a variant along those lines? Define the *saturation* of a set $S$ to be the smallest tail set containing $S$. Suppose $S$ is Borel. Show that so is its saturation.

Comment: Is it obviously false? I mean, it really seems to be, but there's a straight forward exemple?

Comment: A quick way: If the continuum hypothesis fails, start with $S$ of size $\omega_1$. Its saturation has the same size. All Borel sets are either countable or of the same size as $\mathbb R$, which is not $\omega_1$ under the failure of the continuum hypothesis. This is the quickest example I thought of, but you can produce as well examples that do not depend on additional assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

A non principal ultrafilter on the set of natural numbers is a tail set but it is far from Borel. What you are missing is that you need to make use of the fact that your set is Borel (or Lebesgue measurable) so that you can apply something like Lebesgue density theorem.